# Debug C++ graph database server using CLION

Tags: c++, debugging, breakpoints, clion

I attempted to incorporate breakpoints and debug the [JasmineGraph](https://github.com/miyurud/jasminegraph) database server using CLION. However, during debugging, the red-filled circles are transforming into cross circles. This issue arises because the debugger cannot reach the specific code segment. Unfortunately, I am uncertain about the underlying cause of this behavior.

I tried to debug server with CLION tool.This is my configuration.
[debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEdBF.png)

Note that when debugging server is running successfully.